# My pc can't find the fingerprint reader

Tags: hp, fingerprint-reader

I have an HP ENVY x360 15-cn0004ng as the Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

If I try to enable the login with fingerprint, it says **There is no fingerprint reader to access at.

Please contakt the System administrator for help**

At Win10 it works fine.

Does somebody have a clue what to do?

Best Regards
Ese